# How to override Materialize CSS in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, erb, materialize

Due to some questions on this matter being to exact to one's situation, I've decided to re-ask the question: How would one override the Materialize CSS on Ruby on Rails?

Example: Wanting to change the height of the prebuilt `nav`

Where exactly would we create a .scss file and how would we link it to all of our pages on our site (`.html.erb`)? The matter is we might have models on our site that are dynamically loading and need to be styled where ever they may be. An element with the class of `.post-image` should be able to be restyled with CSS.

The issue is we might have a hard time linking the stylesheet properly in our .html.erb files and we can't seem to figure out how to link it properly all over our site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do not repost questions.

Comment: Check https://ghariaonline.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/materialize-css-changing-default-theme-with-sass/